# Magento 2 visibility "catalog" not saving in default store view

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, search, catalogsearch

Magento 2 visibility "catalog" not saving in "default store view" but when store is "All store view" it is saving "catalog" but in default store view when visibility set "catalog" after save it is showing "catalog,search"

Using Magento 2.3.5p1

[image]
Anyone how to solve this?

Comment: Could you please let us know for which section are you talking about?

Comment: @DharaBhatti when adding product from admin

Comment: Check that the scope for the visibility attribute is set to Global or Store View.

Comment: @paj visibility attribute is already set to Global

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what's going on in there :) Your visibility attribute is set as **global** (in the default Magento installation, it has a store view level scope), so my assumption is that there was a change which said that your attribute has to be global from 'now on', but there are some old records in the database from the time when your attribute was 'store level scope'. that's why you see it like this.

first, double check that i am right :)

`select * from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='visibility' and entity_type_id=4) and store_id > 0 and entity_id=<your_product_id>;`

this query will return results if my assumption is correct. so if you want to keep the 'visibility' attribute as global and make it behave correctly on this product, then delete the line:

`delete from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id in (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code='visibility' and entity_type_id=4) and store_id > 0 and entity_id=<your_product_id>;`

make sure you are replacing the '<your_product_id>' with your product's entity_id.

Comment: for this conditions what i have to do now ?

Comment: if you want to keep the attribute as global, you need to delete the store view values from the database, i will update my answer.

Comment: i updated my answer above with the queries you need to first validate the theory, then make it work for your product.

Comment: i have lots of products which we are facing so how can we for multiple products ?

Comment: Remove the end condition 'and entity_id=<your_product_id>' and execute the query. this will remove the store level values for all products for the visibility attribute.

Comment: Also consider marking this as solution so others can see it too. Cheers!

Comment: yes sure I will do soon

Comment: it is working fine(run delete SQL command which you shared) on my localhost, hope it will work on live website without any errors.

Comment: glad to hear this! wish you best of luck!